# Highchart Lang.noData not working

Tags: highcharts

I looked for Add property to `Highchart` for adding some text when no data  available and [I found this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/no-data-to-display/no-data-line/) but it doesn't work when I use it in my application.

My code:

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'No data in pie chart'
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Random data',
        data: []
    }],
    lang :{
        noData : "no data no data no data no data "
    }
});
```

> I test this code in jsfiddle and it worked well.
>
> I use `v5.0.10` of highchart.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: No, nothing ...

Comment: Did you add the `modules/no-data-to-display.js` to your project? it is required.

Comment: No, I didn't add it.

Comment: There is your issue then. Make sure you add that highcharts module after your add the highcharts.js.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved.